# NodeJS no code running after worker code finishes

Tags: node.js, multithreading, promise, node-worker-threads

I'm having an issue with my worker code, currently i have some code that scans through two database tables and finds some matches and then adds some data from one table to the other creating a new table. This is a large set of data so i'm using worker threads to speed this up.

This is all working fine however once the worker threads are complete no other code runs i've tried adding the function `LogData` everywhere i can and it will not run i've even add the `console.log("Finished building merge table")` and that doesn't run either. Even the `parentResolve` does happen as i don't see the `console.log("parentResolve")` message.

if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

```
const calculateFactorialwithWorker = async () => {

    const SCCM = await ProgramDev.find({ "program name": { $not: { $regex: ".*[(]KB*[)]*" } } }).limit(8000)
    const sccmLength = SCCM.length

    mongoose.connection.close()

    return new Promise(async (parentResolve, parentReject) => {
        const numbers = [...new Array(sccmLength)].map((_, i) => i);

        const segmentSize = Math.ceil(sccmLength / userCPUCount);
        const segments = [];

        for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < userCPUCount; segmentIndex++) {
            const start = segmentIndex * segmentSize;
            const end = start + segmentSize;
            const segment = numbers.slice(start, end)
            segments.push(segment);
        }
        try {
            const results = await Promise.all(
                segments.map(
                    segment =>
                        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            const worker = new Worker(workerPath, {
                                workerData: segment,
                            });
                            worker.on('message', resolve);
                            worker.on('error', reject);
                            worker.on('exit', (code) => {
                                if (code !== 0)
                                    reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
                            });
                        })
                ));

            parentResolve(() => {

                console.log("parentResolve")

            })
        } catch (e) {
            parentReject(e)
        }
    });
};

calculateFactorialwithWorker().then(() => {

    console.log("Finished building merge table")
    LogData
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `if else` block in worker `exit` event. When `exit` fired with `code === 0` , there is no resolve/reject to handle it. The promises will not be resolved/rejected.

Ref. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_event_exit

Also, I rewrite your codes a bit because some promises wrapper is unnecessary.

```js
const calculateFactorialwithWorker = async () => {
  try {
    const SCCM = await ProgramDev.find({
      "program name": { $not: { $regex: ".*[(]KB*[)]*" } },
    }).limit(8000);

    const sccmLength = SCCM.length;

    const numbers = [...new Array(sccmLength)].map((_, i) => i);

    const segmentSize = Math.ceil(sccmLength / userCPUCount);
    const segments = [];

    for (let segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < userCPUCount; segmentIndex++) {
      const start = segmentIndex * segmentSize;
      const end = start + segmentSize;
      const segment = numbers.slice(start, end);
      segments.push(segment);
    }

    const promises = segments.map(
      segment =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const worker = new Worker(workerPath, {
            workerData: segment,
          });
          worker.on("message", resolve);
          worker.on("error", reject);
          worker.on("exit", code => {
            if (code !== 0) {
              reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
            } else {
              resolve();
            }
          });
        })
    );

    await Promise.all(promises);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};

calculateFactorialwithWorker()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Finished building merge table");
    LogData();
  })
  .catch(console.log)
  .finally(() => {
    mongoose.connection.close();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i'm still getting the same problem with your code above also now i getting an Error: Error: Worker stopped with exit code 0, however it appears like the code is still working

Comment: @adamWadsworth, I think I know why. The `message` event is never fired by the worker and the `exit` event is fired actually. I add a if else to handle the `exit` event instead. Please check my updates

Comment: @ikhbjs well the `console.log("Finished building merge table")` is now working but it's still not firing off Logdata no error message it just ends and the first line of that function is a `console.log("Starting logging data")`;

Comment: @adamWadsworth, Maybe it should be `LogData()` instead? I just copy your codes with `LogData`. I don't see your LogData function in your codes anyway. If you can provide it, it may be more clear.

Comment: @ikhbjs That sorted out the problem there was also an issue with the `mongoose.connection.close();` being where it was as i needed to call the Database again inside logData so moved it and now everything is working thanks for you help

Comment: @adamWadsworth, You are welcome. I will recommend adding a `finally` block in the end and close the db connection. Please see my updated answer.